# What can be said about the terminal point of the following vector if its initial point is at the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image]

In relation to the points P1 and P2 in the figure, what can you say about the terminal point of the following vector if its initial point is at the origin?

I honestly have no idea what this question is looking for, my best bet is u = OP1 + (1/2)v .. but that doesnt sound like an answer it's looking for... so....

Comment: Isn't the terminal point in question just the midpoint of the segment joining $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: thats a good thing to point out